# Printing list of list (containing integers) in lexicographic order

Tags: python, lexicographic

Task: You are given three integers x, y and z along with an integer n. You have to print a list of all possible coordinates where the sum of is not equal to n. Print Print the list in lexicographic increasing order.

Below is my code. It works fine except for printing in lexicographic order. Is there a better approach to get lexicographic order of list containing integers?

```
from itertools import combinations
lst=[]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    z = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    lst=[[a,b,c]  for b in range(y+1) for c in range(z+1)   for a in range(x+1) ]
   
finallst=[]
for items in combinations(lst,3):
    for nums in items:
       x=sum(nums)
       if x!=n and nums not in finallst:
            finallst.append(nums)

f_finallst= (sorted(map(str,(finallst)))) #converted to string to get lexicographic order
print (f_finallst)
```

My result

```
['[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 1]', '[0, 1, 0]', '[1, 0, 0]', '[1, 1, 1]']
```

Expected result

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Just do `finallst.sort()` without converting the lists to strings.

Comment: When you say lexicographical order, you mean character by character or element by element? By example, which of these is ordered: [[100, 0], [90, 0]] or [[90, 0], [100, 0]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print([coords 
       for coords in itertools.product(range(x+1), range(y+1), range(z+1))
       if sum(coords) != n])
```

Comment: You may add some explanation to improve the usefulness of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
lists=[[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1)
               for j in range(y+1)
               for k in range(z+1) if (i+j+k)!=n]
print(lists)
```

Comment: Explain your answer. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

By using `map(str, finallst)`, you cast each of the element in the list to a `str`. You want to keep the elements as they are, but use `str` as a sorting key.

```
f_finallst= sorted(finallst, key=str)
```

Comment: You don't need string at all!

Comment: For lexicographical order, yes, suppose there is a two-digit number in the list, then it makes a difference

Comment: Ok, Fair enough. But converting the entire list to string might have you comparing numbers with commas or spaces for cases where there are more than one digit leading to unintended results.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Although, I added a comment to ask OP to be more specific about what they mean by lexicographical order.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that adding the lambda function, which basically works as the key for the sort comparison will do the trick. For a detailed explanation read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-of-lists-by-lexicographic-value-and-then-length/)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

orginal_list = [[i, j, k] for k in range(z+1) for j in range(y+1) for i in range(x+1) if i + j + k != n]

sorted_list = sorted(orginal_list, key = lambda i: (len(i), i)) 


print(sorted_list)
```